# Disable caching with AutoTabsRouter - Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, auto-route

I recently upgraded auto_route package and upgraded the tabs to AutoTabsRouter. But, my guarding stopped working. I checked here, it is not supported.

Does anybody faced the same issue?

For now, I am moving my guarding to specific screen but, with TabsRouter, widgets are cached and it is not allowing me to re-build.

How actually can I disable caching for specific screen?

Thanks